# SSRS Horizontal X-Axis displaying single day instead of full month

Tags: reporting-services, charts, axis

I have a bar chart in SSRS with 12 Series, each one representing a months worth of data. (image link below)

If I leave all of the defaults settings for the X-Axis (auto, etc) the bars look perfect, but I can't get the MM/yy to display in the X-Axis.
When I edit the axis properties to Type > scalar, Interval > 1, Interval Type > Months, The axis displays everything just like I want, but the bars then get thin.

It appears that the bars are now only showing a single day out of the month rather than the full month.

For each Series I have the Category Field set to and Expression formatting the date to something like

```
=Format(DateAdd("m",-1,Today()), "Y").
```

Any ideas on how I can get the bars to fill the whole month?

Bar Chart with Thin Lines

[image: Bar Chart with Thin Lines]